# SwifUI 2 : DatePicker display different format of selected Date

Tags: datepicker, swiftui, ios14, swiftui-14.2-defect

I build a iOS 14 DatePicker. When I selected a date from the picker, it some date in format `27 Dec 2020` and some date show in format `26/12/2020`. May I know what is the problem and how can I make it consistent?

[image][image]

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var birthDate = Date()
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            DatePicker(selection: $birthDate, in: Date()..., displayedComponents: .date){
                 Text("Date")
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this on same device, in one run-time? I cannot reproduce this, on my iOS 14.1 it shows `Dec 26, 2020`. If it is on different devices then it might depend on selected OS locale.

Comment: @Asperi yes, in one run-time. I tested in both iOS 14.2 device and simulator. Both show the same problem. Edited with sample result.

Comment: Probably it is one more (and seems not last) defect of 14.2 ... hmm... there are too many, actually, as for one minor update.